# $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} 1/k = a/b$, $(a,b) = 1$ and $p^2\mid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solved it later,thanks to All the people attending to the question
The question has 2 parts,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac1k = \frac ab$$

$\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $p$ is prime $>3$

$i)$ prime $p\mid a$

$ii)$  $p^2\mid a$

The first part I did with inverses, giving  $\equiv$ $p(p-1)/2$
But for the second one I am lost.Thanks in advance and also I know elementary olympiad number theory.

Comment: p>3 i forgot it

Comment: This is a good exercise for you to work on. The result is know as Wolstenholme's theorem. Starting from part $a$, consider how you pair up the terms, and then divide $p$ from the numerator. Then, show that the new numerator is $ \equiv \sum i^2 \equiv  p(p+1)(2p+1)/6$, so we need to exclude $p= 2, 3$ which would cancel out with the denominator of 6.          $\quad$ In fact, a stronger result applies. The statement is true for all integers coprime to 6 (not necessarily prime).

Comment: When you say "elementary olympiad number theory", does that include either the $p$-adic numbers, or localization rings (in this case you could use the ring of rational numbers whose denominators are not divisible by $p$)?

Comment: Sorry Sir, I am not familiar with p-adic numbers and localization rings.I will find it helpful if you can provide a source for these topics

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks, I will try

Comment: @CalvinLin, I am not able to proceed any further.

Comment: Actually nvm I got $\sum_{} {-1/k^2}$
Forgot to use inverses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that unfolds the idea of localization ring in the language of elementary number theory.

Write $S = \{1, \ldots, p-1\}$. Then for $k \in S$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p-k}
= -\frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - p/k}
&= -\frac{1}{k} \left( 1 + \frac{p}{k} + \frac{p^2}{k(k-p)} \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{k} - \frac{p}{k^2} - \frac{p^2}{k^3(k-p)}.
\end{align*}

Using this and the fact that $\sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{p-k}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{k}
&= \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{p-k} \right) \\
&= - \frac{p}{2} \sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{p^2}{2} \sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{k^3(k-p)}.
\end{align*}

Now let $N = [(p-1)!]^4$ for simplicity, and note that the assumption $p>3$ shows that $\gcd(-2N, p) = 1$. Multiplying $-2N$ to both sides of the above equality,

$$ a \cdot \underbrace{(-2N/b)}_{\text{integer}} = p \sum_{k\in S} \underbrace{(N/k^2)}_{\text{integer}} + p^2 \sum_{k\in S} \underbrace{\frac{N}{k^3(k-p)}}_{\text{integer}}. $$

Moreover, $-2N/b$ is also an integer coprime to $p$. In light of this, it suffices to show that

$$ \sum_{k\in S} \frac{N}{k^2} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}. $$

Now for each $k \in S$, write $k^{-1} \in S$ for the modular inverse of $k$ mod $p$, that is, $(k^{-1})k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Then $ k^2 (N/k^2) = N $ shows that $(N/k^2) \equiv N(k^{-1})^2 \pmod {p}$. Moreover, it is clear that $k \mapsto k^{-1}$ is a bijection from $S$ to $S$ itself. So by permuting the summands according to this bijection, we get

$$ \sum_{k\in S} \frac{N}{k^2}
\equiv \sum_{k\in S} N(k^{-1})^2
\equiv \sum_{k\in S} Nk^2
\equiv (N/6)(p-1)p(2p-1) \pmod{p}. $$

Since $p>3$, it follows that $N/6$ is an integer coprime to $p$. Therefore the right-hand side is divisible by $p$ and the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you for the fasinating proof, I could understand it but it felt exhaustive as I haven't seen such rigour before so it took 15 minutes to digest. I have a doubt,what do you mean by "clear that k↦k−1
 is a bijection from S
 to S
 itself. So by permuting the summands according to this bijection, we get"
Also one more thing, what is localization of rings over here, as I felt it to be not out of scope of my study, so if you can pin point it anywhere it will help

Comment: And what was your motivation to take that N and why cannot we do the proof without it?

Comment: @SangchulLee can you clarify this.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Can you elaborate as I didn’t understand it

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque, Sorry, I didn't notice this was a duplicate question.

Comment: @Krave37, The use of $N$ is simply to bring every quotient back to integer, so that the proof can be done in the scope of integers. Other than that, the use of $N$ is completely arbitrary and auxiliary. Indeed, once you know that all the basic arithmetic operations in $R=\{\frac{a}{b}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z},\gcd(b,p)=1\}$ including addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division by a "coprime" to $p$ all carries over to those in $\text{mod }p$ operations (like other users have explained), then you do not need to use $N$ at all.

Comment: To be formal, consider the map $\iota:S\to S$ defined by $\iota(k)=k^{-1}$. Then $\iota(\iota(k))=k$ for all $k\in S$, meaning that $\iota$ is the inverse of $\iota$ itself. In particular, $\iota$ is a bijection from $S$ to $S$ it self. Then for any integer-valued function $f(k)$ on $S$, we have $$\sum_{k\in S}f(k)=\sum_{k\in S}f(\iota(k))$$ because the list $[f(\iota(1)), \ldots, f(\iota(p-1))]$ is just a permutation of the list $[f(1),\ldots,f(p-1)]$, and finite summation does not care about the order in which additions are carried out.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the sum under consideration as $S := \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{k}$.  Then if we reverse the order of the terms, then we get $S$ is also equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{p-k}$.  Therefore, adding the two equations, we see
$$2S = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left( \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{p-k} \right) = p \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{k(p-k)}.$$
So, we have $S = \frac{p}{2} S'$ where we let $S' := \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{k(p-k)}$; now, using the fact that $p > 2$, it will be sufficient to show that $S'$ has a multiple of $p$ in its numerator.

Now, the language used in the comments about localization rings amounts to the following observations:

- Let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be the set of rational numbers which can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b$ are integers and $b$ is not a multiple of $p$.  Then $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is closed under addition and multiplication.
- Furthermore, we can define a function $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \to \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ which sends $\frac{a}{b}$ in the required format to $a b^{-1} \pmod{p}$ where $b^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b \pmod{p}$.  (Part of the proof of this point, if you want to fill in the details, is to show that this is in fact a well-defined function; i.e. if you have two different representations $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a'}{b'}$ of the same element of $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, then $a b^{-1} \equiv a' (b')^{-1} \pmod{p}$.)
- The function $\varphi$ in the previous point preserves both sums and products.
- The function $\varphi$ maps $\frac{a}{b}$ in the required format to $0 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $p \mid a$.

We can use these facts to show that $S' \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.  Also, $\varphi(S') \equiv -\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k^{-1})^2 \pmod{p}$, since $k(p-k) \equiv -k^2 \pmod{p}$.  Now, observe that for $p > 2$, multiplying $k$ by 2 permutes the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ (with the inverse permutation being multiplication by the multiplicative inverse of $2\pmod{p}$).  Applying this permutation to the terms of the sum in $\varphi(S')$, we see that
$$\varphi(S') \equiv -\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} ((2k)^{-1})^2 \equiv -4^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (k^{-1})^2 \equiv 4^{-1} \varphi(S') \pmod{p}.$$
Therefore, $4 \varphi(S') \equiv \varphi(S') \pmod{p}$, so $3 \rho(S') \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.  Since $p > 3$, we can conclude $\varphi(S') \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.  In other words, $S'$ must have a multiple of $p$ in its numerator, as we wanted to show.

Comment: Is localization of rings basically inverses if I want to understand it at a high school level for now?

Comment: Yes, the idea of localization is precisely the idea of taking inverses of a restricted set of integers (or taking inverses of a restricted set of polynomials to get a restricted set of rational functions, etc.).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, at the time I wrote this I didn't realize it was a duplicate question.  What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

This is my other solution,
$a/b = x$

$2x = \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)} (p/k(p-k))$

$p|x$

Now to show $p^2|x$
In the realm of $modp$

$1/k(p-k) \equiv -1/k^2 $
(I forgot to use inverses here)
With inverses we will get another random permutation, as another inverse shall exist due to modulo prime.

The summation reduces to $\sum_{}^{p-1} -1/k^2$ giving  $x = -(p-1)(p)(2p-1)/12$

For $p > 3$ It satisfies, Thanks to DanielSchepler

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).